# Transforming a dataframe by joining values of two different columns

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, row

I am working with the following dataframe called `example` :

> structure(list(person = c(1, 2, 3), animal = c(4, 5, 6), type = c("a",
> "b", "c")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

I am looking for a way to create a new dataframe containing a new column, "value", that joins the numeric values of "person" and "animal" as rows, and would replicate the corresponding character value in "type".

The structure of this second dataframe would like the following in `example2`:

> structure(list(value = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), being = c("person",
> "person", "person", "animal", "animal", "animal"), type = c("a",  "b",
> "c", "a", "b", "c")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
> -6L))

How could I achieve this using functions?

(The idea would be to use this method for a much larger dataframe)

All the best,

Cameron

Comment: `tidyr::pivot_longer(example, cols = -type)`